# How to improve the perfomance of my A* path finder?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, a-star

So basically I coded an A* pathfinder that can find paths through obstacles and move diagnolly. I basically implemented the pseudocode from [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) into real code and also used a binary heap method to add and delete items from the openlist.

Using binary heap led to significant performance boost , about 500 times faster than the insert sorting algorithm I used before.

the problem is that it still takes around on average 1.5 million nanoseconds which is around .0015 of a second.

So the question is,  my plan is to make a tower defense game where the pathfinding for each mob needs to update everytime I add  a tower to the map. If I were to have around a maximum of 50ish mobs on the map, that means it will take around .0015 *  50 = .075 seconds to update all paths for the entire mob. The game basically ticks( all the ingame stuff updates) every 1/60 seconds which is .016 of a second, so the problem is that it takes longer to update the paths than it takes to tick, which will lead to massive lag. So how should I go about this? DO I need to find a better algorithm for sorting the openlist or somehow divide the pathfinding tasks so that each tick only does X number of pathfinding tasks as opposed to all of them.

Comment: Your question is way too specific for the level of description you gave us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than searching from each enemy to the checkpoint, search outwards from the checkpoint to every enemy at once.  This way, rather than doing 50 searches, you only need to do one.

More specifically, just do a breadth-first search *(or [djikstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), if your graph is weighted)* from the player outwards, until every enemy has been reached.

You could alter this strategy to work with A* by changing your heuristic `EstimatedDistanceToEnd` *(aka `h(x)`)* to be the minimum estimate to any enemy, but with a lot of enemies this may end up being slower than the simpler option.  The heuristic must be [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) for this to work.

---

Additionally, make sure you are using the [correct tie-breaking criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623630/).

Also, and most importantly, remember that **you don't need to run your pathfinder every single frame** for most games - often you can get away with only once or twice a second, or even less, depending on the game.

If that is *still* too slow, you could look into using [D* lite](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aaai02b.pdf) to reuse information between subsequent searches.  But, I would bet money that running a single breadth-first search will be more than fast enough.

*(copied from my answer to [a similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43860) on gamedev)*

Comment: Is Djisktra or breadth first faster than the A* pathfinder? I still don't really understand your explanation about the EstimatedDistanceToEnd, but I am very interested in trying out the djistra/breadth first if they lead to significant performance boost. Also I read the article you provided, but it doesn't go into how it can be used to navigate paths to multiple targets (in my case enemies). I also googled both algorithms and haven't found any noob friendly articles that I can use to write code with. Do you know of any articles like    http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Comment: Also will breadth first search give me the shortest path? I read the article and it seems way simpler than A*. I just don't know whether it will give me the shortest path or not. pls respond

Comment: Thanks, I think I sort of understand DJikstra/ breadth first. Tell me if I'm wrong, but Djikstra basically sounds like a simpler A* without having to calculate the heuristic/ the openlist sorting, and since I have different movement costs --( N,W,S,E) movements will cost 10, while NW, NE, SE,SW movements will cost 14-- I am guessing I'll be using djikstra, not breadth first.

Comment: Lastly, it sounds like djikstra will have better performance since it will be doing less calculating, and gets rid of all the unnecessary extra code that I'd need to write for reassigning the path for each enemy if I were to use A*. So i guess my question is, when do we use A* as opposed to djikstra? I spent all this time learning / coding an A* with binary heap only to find out it's unneeded for my tower defense game. How do games like StarCraft that use A* for 100+ entities perform so well? DO they use some kind of special A* algorithm?

Comment: @GayLord: To oversimplify:  BFS is the "obvious" algorithm; Dijkstra's is extension to BFS that works on weighted graphs; A\* is an extension to Dijkstra's that speeds up the algorithm when an `EstimatedDistance` heuristic is available *(setting the heuristic to `0` is exactly equivalent to Dijkstra's algorithm)*.  Games like Starcraft probably do what I explained above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Essentially, A* is for path-finding from a single source to one or more destinations. However, in tower defense (depending on your rules of course), it is about multiple sources navigating around a map.

So for this, Floyd's algorithm seems more optimal. However, you could have your A* algorithm find paths for unit **groups** instead of individual units, which should optimize your calculation times.

Comment: -1 Floyd-Warshall is for finding all-pairs shortest paths.  This will be **horribly** inefficient for a tower defense game.  See my answer.

Comment: So iam the guy who originally asked the question. My goal right now is to create a game like desktop tower defense. You can add / delete towers on the map and the enemies will change their path accordingly. Obviously, I believe doing this with A* will be really slow because I plan to have at least 50 entities on the map and having each of them recalculate their path every time the player adds/ deletes a tower would take a long time. So what algorithm should I use? So far,people have recommended quadtree, d lite, djikstra, jump point search,but can't really find any newbie friendly tut on those

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You could have it customized for a tower defense application. Essentially, whenever a node changes, it will re-calculate the cost to that node from surrounding tiles and for each surrounding tile, _if_ it has changed, the algorithm is invoked on them. So no need for "game-wide" re-calculation. A* wouldn't be optimal since usually the # of sources outweighs the number of tiles on the board, and you'll need to re-fire the algorithm each time "something" has changed...

Comment: @GayLord: D\*-lite and JPS are overkill; and quadtree is unrelated.  Floyd-Warshall is the right answer to the wrong problem.  Just use breadth-first search using the checkpoint as the start, and ending when you reach all the units, as suggested in my answer.  It is insanely simple to understand and implement - see for example [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/Hing/BFSDFSTutorial.htm)

Comment: I am using something similar to this already. What I need is a way to change paths dynamically whenever a new tower is placed or deleted on the map without having to calculate the path for each enemy

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you can back-search from the exit towards all the creeps, so you need to explore your maze only once.