# Search Algorithm and Dynamically Behaving Obstacles

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

I am concerned with an environment containing just doors, keys and walls. Doors can be passed through if a key has been 'picked up' (i.e. the node containing a key has been visited).

The problem is to find a path between a given point A and B. An optimal solution is not necessary.

Let us represent a door with "D", key with a "K" and a wall with a "#", now consider the environment below. Goal is B, origin is A. We will represent empty squares with "."

```
###..........K
#BD...A.......
###...........
```

Now, obviously in this case we must visit the node containing K before moving towards goal B. Currently I am using AStar, with a heuristic discount for visiting "key" nodes with manhattan distance to the goal, however, when K is far away, this approach struggles as it consumes too much memory and time.

I am curious to see which algorithms you believe best suit this particular problem? Or is my algorithm choice correct but heuristic poor? Please advise, and as I am new please be as explanatory as possible in response.

Cheers.

Comment: I would just do two separate searches, one from A-to-K, one from K-to-B, with just manhatten distance as the heuristic *(make sure you [break ties correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623630/15624021#15624021))*.  Unfortunately, this approach breaks down if there are many keys, but that case is NP-complete anyways (it's the travelling-salesman problem).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It is not always the case that we must visit K however. If you remove the the door "D" from the environment, visiting K isn't necessary any more. Interesting that you mention tie breaking, as I had literally just read an article on it and it has sped up my algorithm a little bit.

Comment: In that case, do a path-find from A-to-B, and if no path exists, then do A-to-K-to-B.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as a two-phase problem. In the first phase, use [automated planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_planning) algorithms to determine feasible sequences of events, where an event is visiting a key/door/point B. A [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) could be helpful in determining over time whether two locations are connected via empty space and unlocked doors. In the second phase, use A* to realize the plan.